# when making subdomain for images in opencart, Images not found

Tags: opencart

```
  this is my config file. I have changed for image subdomain but images do not load.
```

`// HTTP
define('HTTP_SERVER', 'http://a2zfitnessmart.com/');
**define('HTTP_IMAGE', 'http://img.a2zfitnessmart.com/');**
// HTTPS
 define('HTTPS_SERVER', 'http://a2zfitnessmart.com/');
**define('HTTPS_IMAGE', 'http://img.a2zfitnessmart.com/');**

// DIR
define('DIR_APPLICATION', '\www.a2zfitnessmart.com/catalog/');
define('DIR_SYSTEM', '\www.a2zfitnessmart.com/system/');
define('DIR_DATABASE', '\www.a2zfitnessmart.com/system/database/');
define('DIR_LANGUAGE', '\www.a2zfitnessmart.com/catalog/language/');
define('DIR_TEMPLATE', '\www.a2zfitnessmart.com/catalog/view/theme/');
define('DIR_CONFIG', '\www.a2zfitnessmart.com/system/config/');
**define('DIR_IMAGE', '\img.a2zfitnessmart.com/');**
define('DIR_CACHE', '\www.a2zfitnessmart.com/system/cache/');
define('DIR_DOWNLOAD', '\www.a2zfitnessmart.com/download/');
define('DIR_LOGS', '\www.a2zfitnessmart.com/system/logs/'); 

   </pre>`

Comment: Have you created the subdomain, its directory on your server and put your images in there?

Comment: yes, I have created subdomain and copied all images.